# SSIS File System Task copy file from one server to another

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS to copy a file from one server to another. I am also using VS on my labtop. I created two variables (Destination and Source) picture attached. SSIS does not like the givens paths format is not supported

[screen shot of SSIS package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re0lA.png)

Comment: What is the error you are getting? This is not a good question as is.

Answer (score 0):

The second variable is neither a UNC - starting with a \ - nor a correct drive/directory specification. I'd remove everything before the G:\ and try again.